# Превью pdf-документов в IE в окне приложения

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net, pdf

На данный момент не получается реализовать предпросмотр pdf документов в одном окне приложения (SPA проект), без открытия новой вкладки. IE открывает документы в новом окне в формате Adobe Reader. 
Для остальных браузерова предпросмотр работает.

Ресёрч показал, что библиотеки `AngularJS PDF viewer`, `PDF.js`, `PDFObject` могут помочь добиться желаемого результа.

Но есть ли возможность реализовать предпросмотр в IE, без использования сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтобы отобразить PDF файл на странице, используйте:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="path/to/file.pdf"></iframe>
```

В версии IE11 данный код отображает документ на странице.

Если вы пытаетесь отобразить PDF файл, загруженный через File API, то, к сожалению, IE11 имеет баг, который не позволит отобразить документ через blob, вам нужно будет произвести конвертацию в base64 URL и использовать этот URL. ([Баг на Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1600008/link-to-pdf-file-created-with-url-createobjecturl-wont-displayed-in-iframe-or-object))